# Offline HTTP explore with Java

Tags: java, http, url, httprequest, offline-browsing

I made a little research about how to request http sites and explore them offline; I found this as one possible answer:

http://www.javaworld.com/jw-05-2000/jw-0518-offload.html

but the thing is, it's not so complete or intuitive. Does anyone have one good literatur source about this topic that I could use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/): **Java HTML Parser**

> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides
>   a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the
>   best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.

Reading the content is as easy as this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

Comment: I got the idea of the jsoup reading the documentation but the thing is, this connect method open the connection and take objects and sub-objects from the URL, and then I need to handle the save part on my HD?

Comment: @VictorOliveira JSoup loads the entire html into a Document object. You can traverse that document and fetch the nodes.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get the point of how I'm gonna acess this object and his content. Wont I download it as one file?

Comment: @VictorOliveira document object has a lot of utility methods to read different parts of the page. Check this tutorial to get some feel of it: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/

Comment: I'm thinking here how to merge both ways cos I already have the connection and the download of the html to my HD..but the problem is, the links that comes with the html I download are not local acessible, for that I would need something like jsoup - Or am I missunderstanding something? || btw thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Use Jsoup:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Strin html=doc.html();
//save html in a file
```